# iOS Can you test Offer Codes with a Sandbox Account?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

In AppStoreConnect you can now create Offer Codes. Upon implementation, I discovered that they bypass sandbox accounts. Has anyone found a way to test these using a Sandbox Account?

Comment: No information about it. I think no for now.

Answer (score 0):

"No, we can't test it through the sandbox. We can only test it with the StoreKit file. Here is the official Apple link.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_at_all_stages_of_development_with_xcode_and_the_sandbox

Please check 'Redeem an offer code for an auto-renewable subscription'portion in the above link."